# Run Exchange 2010 management console locally, connect remotely

Tags: remote-desktop, exchange, exchange-2010

Is it possible to install and run Exchange Management console (for Exchange 2010) on my laptop and connect to a remote exchange server?

This would save me having to RDP into the remote exchange box (I'd just need to be on the VPN).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This is possible. Install the Exchange Management Tools.

Edit: Vista, 7, or 2008 only. Here's a technet link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232090.aspx

Comment: Many thanks Hyppy, unfortunately the Exchange Management Tools require that I'm on a domain (we're running the Exchange as a standalone unit)... so I just need to join the domain and I'll be away.  Thanks!